# Press ctrl+alt+0 to explodes My character

Tags: rigging

I just want to modify the composition of the camera.

But i Press ctrl+alt+0 to explodes My character

here is a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/0UgAtkNy1dE

here is the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2k9mj85dm8ok3ha/perona06_02%20af%20%20with%20automatic%20weights.blend?dl=0

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have anything *parented* to the camera? Does manually moving or rotating the camera (rather than Ctrl+Alt+0) also cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties* panel > *Scene* > *Scene* > *Camera*, switch back the dropdown menu to *Camera*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have inadvertently set part of your mesh to act as the active camera. This can be easily done by selecting an object and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> - and it means that when you are trying to move the “active camera” it is pulling your mesh and rig apart, causing the distortion.

To resolve this simply select your actual camera and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> to set that as the current active camera. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> should now be back to moving your actual camera rather than the mesh.